# How to select next 2 (or more than 2) items using jQuery .next()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

using jQuery's `.next` function I want to show next 2 items. By default it selects only just next item.

I need control, like sometimes I need next 2, sometime next 3

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and a [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector, for example:

```
.nextAll(':lt(2)') //next 2
.nextAll(':lt(3)') //next 3
```

[Try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HvPxM/1/). If you need it to be programmatic (instead of string concatenation) and change it easily, use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) instead:

```
.nextAll().slice(0, 2) //next 2
.nextAll().slice(0, 3) //next 3
```

This method allows you to pass as a parameter the number you need a bit easier.  [You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HvPxM/).

Comment: @Reigel - I know right. I have 10 rep points till I hit the cap for the day and go to sleep, but am scared with Nick awake I won't get them.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to select the next number of elements and include the selected element you can do something like:

```
$('div#myTarget').nextAll('div').andSelf().slice(0,4)
```

The above code returns the next 4 div elements after the div myTarget and includes the myTarget div itself.

`.slice(0,4)` selected the next 4 elements and `.andSelf()` included the original selected element

Answer (score 2):

Use `.nextAll` instead of `.next` to get all following siblings, and then use `.slice` to narrow that down to a range.